# Django CMS absolute url for Elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-cms

i write a command for django app like this :

```
for p in Article.public.all():
    data += '{"index": {"_id": "%s", "_type": "article"}}\n' % p.pk
    data += json.dumps({
        "title": p.title,
        "category": p.category.category,
        "content_type": p.content_type,
        "duration": p.get_audio_duration(),
        "thumbnail": p.get_thumbnail(),
        "date": datetime.strftime(p.date, '%d.%m.%Y'),
        "url": p.get_absolute_url(),
        "content": p.content
    }) + '\n'

response = requests.put('{}/radio_index/_bulk'.format(settings.ES_URL), data=data)
```

`get_absolute_url` method looks like this:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tv_article_hook:article_tv_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

I am using Django CMS apphooks. Apphook urls are:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
                       url(r'^$', ArticleTvListView.as_view(), name='article_tv_list'),
                       url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', ArticleTvView.as_view(), name='article_tv_detail')
                   )
```

When i am using `get_absolute_url` in template or in REST api it works fine. But when i run command via `manage.py feed_index` code fails on `p.get_absolute_url` with error:

`django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'article_tv_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': 'some slug'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Show your URLs. Also note that by building up your data like that you have ended up with something that is not valid JSON.

Comment: I edit question with urls. You are right that json is not valid but i follow Elastic bulk api from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) and it looks same.

Comment: Hello there, does your project have multiple languages?

Comment: @Paulo No I dont have multiple languages.

Comment: @viliam I assume you also get a NoReverseMatch error when trying get_absolute_url() for that one object in the shell? Maybe get the object id when it fails and use it to test on the django shell.

Comment: @Paulo From shell it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure that Django itself, not just CMS, knows the app's namespace, `tv_article_hook`.

I suspect that is registered with CMS, but not a namespace which Django knows about. Now depending on what version of Django you're using there's a couple of ways to define the namespace for Django. But have a read of the [application docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#for-application-authors), essentially you can define your own app config like so;

```
# tv_article/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'tv_article.apps.TVArticleConfig'

# tv_article/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class TVArticleConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'tv_article'
    verbose_name = "TV Article"
```

With that setup, you should then be able to modify your code like so (removing '_hook' from your CMS namespace as well because thats a CMS term, but we're just talking about a Django app here);

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('tv_article:article_tv_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: I am using Django 1.8.13 and Django-CMS 3.2.5 and point of using CMS hooks is that if i 'hook' Django App to `/sk/article/bla/bla/` and article slug is 'best-article' than result of `reverse('tv_article_hook:article_tv_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})` is `/sk/article/bla/bla/best-article`. It means that when i decide in future change hook to page '/sk/article/' result will be '/sk/article/best-article'. I think that this is more about Django CMS itself.